# diable 3D touch functionality for iOS devices using CSS in React application

Tags: ios, css, reactjs, react-router, 3dtouch

I am creating a React application which works for both Desktop and Mobile.
The application required non functionality of 3D touch feature in iOS devices(6s OR more).

I have the following code snippet for `a` tag and `NavLink` tag.

Case 1:

```
navLinks =
  <a key={item.label + i} href={HomePageURL + item.navTo} role="button" target="_self">
    {item.label}
  </a>
```

Case 2:

```
navLinks =
  <NavLink key={item.label + i} to={item.navTo} target="_self">
    {item.label}
  </NavLink>
```

CSS code:

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

How to disable the 3D touch when we click on any on the links on the iOS device (6s or above only)? Present functionality enter code here has 3D touch enabled.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do with just CSS and JS

Comment: I think it is possible, I have tried the same using below code. It worked 
`
<a onClick={()=> this.props.history.push("/FSRSearch")}  role="button" className={styles.searchResultLink}>
`
Now I want to try using it with href tag instead of onClick event